# Probability of 3 people having birthday in March

Tags: probability

If there are 3 people, what’s the probability that all 3 are born in March? None of them are born in a leap year and there are 31 days in March.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Is the probability that one woman/man is born on day $i$ equal to $\frac1{365}$?

Comment: $\frac {31}{365}^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that all days are equally likely to be a person's birthday, and that the three people's birthdays are independent events, then the probability is just the product of the probability of the individual events: $\left(\frac{31}{365}\right)^3$.

Empirically, these assumptions could both likely be false.